# Real Analysis: Affine Maps and Closures of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, convex-analysis

my task is to show that for a set $G \subset \mathbb R^n$, we have

$T(cl(conv(G))\subseteq cl(conv(T(G))$
where
$T$ is an affine map and $cl$ denotes closure of a set and $conv$ denotes the convex hull of a set.

Note that convex hull of a set is the set of all convex combinations of points from that set.
This seems easy on the surface but for some reason I get stuck.

Attempt at Proof:

Let $x \in T(cl(conv(G))$. Then $x=T(y)$ where $y \in cl(conv(G))$. This implies that $y=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha x_{k}+(1-\alpha)y_{k}$ where $x_{k} \subseteq G$ and $y_{k} \subseteq G$.

Hence, let $\alpha \in [0,1]$:
\begin{align*}
x&=T(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \alpha x_{k}+(1-\alpha)y_{k})\\
&=\alpha T(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_{k})+(1-\alpha)T(\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} y_{k})\\
\end{align*}

But then here I get stuck since I believe I am supposed to show $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}x_{k} \in G$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}y_{k} \in G$.

But this isn't necessarily true since $G$ isn't necessarily closed so I'm confused. What mistake am I making? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1** $T(cl(E)) \subseteq cl(T(E))$ for every set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. If $y \in T(cl(E))$, let $y = T(\lim x_n)$. Since $T$ is continuous, $y = \lim T(x_n) \in cl(T(E))$.

**Step 2** $T(conv(G)) \subseteq conv(T(G))$. Let $y \in T(conv(G))$, and $T(x) = a + Bx$ the affine map. Then $y = T(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)w) = a + \alpha B x + (1-\alpha)Bw = \alpha T(x) + (1-\alpha)Tw \in conv(T(G))$ with $x,w,\in G$.

Finally, apply the above with $E = conv(G)$ and use the fact that $cl(E) \subseteq cl(F)$ if $E \subseteq F$.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, I proved step 2 but did not do Step 1, using continuity was a good idea.